# How to create a facebook messeger DYNAMIC carausel card using dialogflow inline editor node.js?

Tags: node.js, facebook, dynamic, carousel, dialogflow-es

Iam trying to create a carousel for facebook messenger using dialog flow.
The following Static carousel custom payload code works fine under the FB Messenger response section. But I don't know how to create a DYNAMIC carousal for fb messenger with dialogflow using node.js inline editor. Please help, iam pretty new to dialogflow.

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "generic",
        "elements": [
          {
            "subtitle": "subtitle",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "payload": "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD",
                "title": "btn1",
                "type": "postback"
              }
            ],
            "title": "title1!",
            "image_url": "img_url"
          },
          {
            "subtitle": "Subtitle2",
            "image_url": "img_url"
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "postback",
                "title": "btn2",
                "payload": "DEVELOPER_DEFI2ED_PAYLOAD"
              }
            ],
            "title": "title2!"
          },
          {
            "image_url": "img_url"
            "subtitle": "Subtitle3",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "btn3",
                "payload": "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD",
                "type": "postback"
              }
            ],
            "title": "title3!"
          }
        ]
      },
      "type": "template"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it dinamically with DB information or with Context Variables info.